# Shifting from Sandbox to Production in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox

We have just connected sandbox with MC so there is nothing much in the MC apart from synced contacts from sandbox and couple of queries and DE.

Should I just disconnect the salesforce integration from MC and then install the MC connect app in the SF Prod? (nothing to do in sandbox in that case).

Or can we have both connected at the same time with the single BU?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to disconnect the integration from MC which is connected to your sandbox. Then, you have to configure the MC Connect app again in Prod in the similar way.
2. You cannot connect a single BU to two different Sales/Service Cloud Orgs.(Reference - [Multi Org Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5))